# Contest for an Image for our blender nation article

Tags: discussion, contest, site-promotion

Bart, who runs [blendernation.com](http://blendernation.com), has agreed to run an article when our site graduates. All articles have a featured image; we need one.

So this is a call for artwork. The size for featured image on an article is 728px wide by 336px tall.

There is no set theme (as I have no idea what should go there.) :)
Bonus points for any image that portrays blender stack exchange in some way.

Go nuts and have fun, make anything awesome.
It could be of a scene from another world, or a black hole (@gandalf3). It could be an epic mech standing over a burning stack of blenders (@x-27). It could be a massive pile of the most expensive watches (@NᴏᴠɪᴄᴇIɴDɪsɢᴜɪsᴇ). Or even a radish, large cow, or a bottle of milk. (@ARadish, @GiantCowFilms @zeffii) Etc.

Yes, some rules... (I'm not going to copy all of the guru's rules)

- Keep the image the same size or aspect resolution as the featured image (728px by 336px).
- Vote for the image(s) you would like to see as the header image.
- This is open for submissions until **November 22, 2015**

<sub><sup>Any of the moderators of BSE (me) at their direction may anytime alter this post and contest; remove and or add images and submissions; declare a winner of the grand prize (nothing); alter the final image; or do just about anything else they want. Including but not limited to whacking people with a large [ban hammer](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21176822#21176822). :)</sup></sub>

Comment: That fine print..

Comment: "Go nuts and have fun" - Sure, but please don't make this a chat in-joke, remember who this is for (hint: people who don't get chat in-jokes).

Comment: Does this mean that we will get new graphics and I will lose all of my privileges shortly after the 22nd?

Comment: @X-27 http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25100567#25100567

Comment: How did you happen to pick the 22nd? Wouldn't the 27th have been better?

Comment: Maybe something with a bold big "stackexchage" text would be funny, in a way... :) mine is not a typo, of course...

Comment: I suggest we don't allow voting until a specific deadline, otherwise the earlier entries will have a *huge* advantage simply for being around longer.

Comment: It would be nice to know what our logo will be so we could include that in the artwork.

Comment: @PGmath I would too.

Comment: November 22 in which time zone?

Comment: @Mentalist Alaska time which is UTC -10, or just look [here](http://www.timeanddate.com/countdown/generic?iso=20151122T235901&p0=18&msg=Countdown+Timer&font=cursive&csz=1).

Comment: @David Just an idea to generate content: Can we also have a full article including an interview with all the moderators (if they like) and some of the best questions/answers in order to get a first impression of the site?

Comment: Great idea! I was thinking some of the question and answers, but a quick interview with the mods, is great!

Answer (score 9):

[image]

I thought about how the `?` sign resambles to an hook. Next step was to draw a reversed hook that help another to get out of the mud. Then the mud became a sea to match Blender logo's color palette.

It looked not so bad till I realized that ["the thing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Thing_%281982_film%29) in the middle (believe me or not but it's just a man with a fishing rod...damn waves) catches **too much attention**. Shame on me...

---

I'll post here another experiment with more or less the same intention:

[image]

I thought about a kind of "collaborative art" where everyone can contribute by giving one [material](https://www.google.it/search?q=%3F&biw=1858&bih=985&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMI6sHzl_v5yAIVS7gaCh3OBgay#tbm=isch&tbs=rimg%3ACSM2kMsgQWT4IjjwV7Z6ifMia3oOj1G4Ru91xi4iOdLyzHK59fqvZa-S7Q3cHIccuNiTYJzjIANRj3Wu7Ee6T-9ksyoSCfBXtnqJ8yJrEYMfLaaJ9wDEKhIJeg6PUbhG73UROwiSVSSXkZoqEgnGLiI50vLMchE04imk6GVGNioSCbn1-q9lr5LtEVHsMxFW9V84KhIJDdwchxy42JMRlh9L9OL0_1ncqEglgnOMgA1GPdRFXJL63mUA69CoSCa7sR7pP72SzEfOixhTDuVLG&q=%3F) to an object (maybe that remember a question/answer that has a meaning for him) to give an sense of **community**.

Do you think it would come up good? Maybe with the site's logo in the middle coverd by `?`?

Comment: I love this idea! How would you go about implementing it, though?

Comment: Probably by providing a public template, collect the blendfiles and append the materials manually (they will require a proper arrangement in the scene).

Comment: Well, I'm down for it, if you decide to do it.

Comment: I'll withdraw this idea @IncessantLee as it didn't get the wide acclaim required for this kind of projects. Maybe it'll get luckier in the 1st year anniversary competition :)

Comment: @Carlo Had a few undelete votes so I restored it. I think these are pretty good and you should keep them. Let me know if you want it removed again.

Comment: Thanks @iKlsR for your kindness, but I'm wondering if leaving it open doesn't mess up the votecount, as there are "two in one". Apart from this, it's fine for me to keep them

Comment: @Carlo Thanks for your effort. I really like your idea of the second one, but I think it's too grey for a header image, which should attract attention. Just an idea: what about coloring the question marks like http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/17934/3710 for a more friendy feel and introduce a bit fog and more zdepth? If you like the ideas just let me know whether I can help :)

Comment: I agree with you @poor, I dreamt of it as colorful, rich and glittered piece too. Though, I also believe that this idea looses too much (if not all) of its strenght if it is not run as community project, so I'm not personally inclined to develop it further on my own. Anyway thanks for your kind offer and suggestions!

Answer (score 8):

Alright, here is the one gandalf3, TARDIS Maker, cegeaton and I worked on:

[image]

<sup>Few final things being touched up still</sup>

## Information

For [those of you who don't watch movies](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2217/david) this is closely based of the final scene of [Raiders of the Lost Ark](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082971/?ref_=nv_sr_1).

[image]

The idea is centered around what our site is, an organized collaborative collection of useful blender information. A warehouse of blender info.

We took some liberties with the original image, in added question tags with actual question ID's on them, as well as populating the scene with workers (Empty is not an adjective for this site), and making it cleaner and more inviting. We also added little post boxes, which are either Questions, Answers or Accepted Answers, as denoted by the letter and or color.

The idea for this image is to be a **metaphor for our site** everything is carefully thought through. It is infinite in potential, and contains a massive amount of carefully maintained information.

The monkeys standing on each other shoulders are a metaphor for editing, since they are building on the work of others.

**Notes**

I wanted to put some subtle things in:

- There are three monkeys with mod hats. Guess which one is which :D

  - One of them happens to be standing near a giant crate of reputation
  - Another one just happens to be tagging something
  - The third one is (and has been) pushing a cart representing our site
- There is an equal number of accepted answer boxes (green) as there are orange question boxes. Afterall, it would be great if every question had an accepted answer :)

### This image will be updated

We are not done with it. We will be adding more monkeys and textures; we will be adjusting the lighting and materials. We won't change the overall theme, so your vote is safe. Please comment for anything you think needs to be addressed

Comment: We are still working on this, as allowed. Why the downvote?

Comment: Nice use of the Stencil font! (A-Team font) I can't seem to find my mech in that render. Is it really small?

Comment: Ha, love it. I'm sure our avid users will as well.

Comment: Love it!  Are you going to continue the piles of crates on the sides to go to the horizon?  They look kind of funny stopping like they do now.

Comment: @PGmath Yes on ths sides, I'm not sure what to do with the horizon, we already have several thousand creates in the image, so its become a bit hard to manage.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms Are you using particle instancing for the crates?

Answer (score 6):

### Fortunate

[image: Your lucky day :-)]

**View the uncompressed full-res original [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/686388/posts/stackexchange/blendernation_fortunate.png).**

Because Blender Stack Exchange is a place where you can get high quality answers to help you take your Blender skills to the next level.

It reads:

```
You will soon conquer your fear of UV mapping.

Lucky Numbers:  2,  7,  6
```

Why did I pick UV mapping? Just because I think it's something that intimidates a lot of new users. I remember avoiding it like the plague for a while before I felt comfortable with it.

Thanks for any and all support.

Comment: While I get your point, we shouldn't advertise that you get your questions answered out of luck. BSE is a database, not a lottery.

Comment: @DalekMaker It's not that you get your questions answered out of luck. It's that people are lucky to discover BSE, and lucky to have it as a resource. While it is a database, it is also more than just a stockpile of questions and answers. I consider it a community of users who are enthusiastic about sharing knowledge. You can find more than just facts here - you can gain Blender wisdom. :-)

Comment: I love this, so simple and relatable (even if UV mapping isn't your plague). Plus everyone loves a fortune cookie.

Answer (score 6):

With the arrival of our new theme, I thought it would be a good idea to suggest something different from a render image: a screenshot of our site (We will get another one when the design is actually pushed).

[image]

Boring it may be, This is still a safe bet, and shows what our site looks like (literally) to the outside. It also shows off the new theme, which is about the only thing to change during the graduation, other than an extreme loss of privileges for most of us D:

Answer (score 0):

A unarmed and *almost* totally harmless **Forklift Mech**. For moving pallets and crates full of questions and answers.

[image: Picture of Mech]

By the way, you should upvote [GiantCowFilms' entry](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/959/5426). A different colored version of this awesome mech is in there if you look really carefully. The scale is horribly off - the mech should be way bigger in his entry, but it is there, so it should get votes.

**EDIT:**

GiantCowFilms must have changed his entry, as this mech is now much smaller, is painted a dark color, and it is now in a shadow. You will have a Very hard time finding it.